# Hostname / VPN / NFS / Kerberos

Tags: vpn, nfs, kerberos

At home I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 with Kerberised NFS Shares.
The NFS clients obtain their full FDQN via DHCP.

When away from home and trying to access NFS shares via VPN, Kinit fails with:

```
kinit: Cannot determine realm for host (principal host/hostname@)
```

The realm is somedomain.internal, so `kinit` should be trying to get a ticket for "host/hostname@somedomain.internal".

I have a `/etc/krb5.conf` file on each client which specifies [realms], [domain_realm] and with [libdefaults] default_realm.